# error in SQL syntax, I can't find the error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I can't find the error after 3 hours trying. Can someone help my ?

this is my query =

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `card`(ProductName,ProductBarcode,ProductPakking,ProductPresent,ProductMinimuim,FotoUrl,DBid) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '" . $ProductName . "','" . $ProductBarcode . "','" . $ProductPakking . "','" . $ProductPresent . "','" . $ProductMinimuim . "','" . $FotoUrl . "','" . $DBid ."') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM `card` WHERE `ProductName` = " . $ProductName . ",`ProductBarcode` = " . $ProductBarcode . ",`ProductPakking` = " . $ProductPakking . ",`ProductPresent` = " . $ProductPresent . ",`ProductMinimuim` = " . $ProductMinimuim . ",`FotoUrl` = " . $FotoUrl . ",`DBid` = " . $DBid ." ) LIMIT 1;";
```

This is when I echo my query =

```
INSERT INTO `card`(ProductName,ProductBarcode,ProductPakking,ProductPresent,ProductMinimuim,FotoUrl,DBid)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'brood','8717333541583','zak','-1937','11','img/img.svg','3') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM `card` WHERE
        `ProductName` = 'brood',
        `ProductBarcode` = '8717333541583',
        `ProductPakking` = 'zak',
        `ProductPresent` = '-1937',
        `ProductMinimuim` = '11',
        `FotoUrl` = 'img/img.svg',
        `DBid` = '3' )
) LIMIT 1
```

> Error
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`ProductBarcode` = ,`ProductPakking` = ,`ProductPresent` = ,`ProductMinimuim` = ' at line 1

Comment: Are your variables empty? You could try echoing the generated query and checking it directly in the db...

Comment: @FirstOne no there not empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `$ProductName` is not an integer, so you'd need to include that in quotes here:

```
WHERE `ProductName` = '" . $ProductName . "'
```

Also, please note, you **SHOULD NOT** be concatenating variables into a string like that. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for info about how bad this is.

An updated SQL statement **PLEASE DON'T USE THIS, BIND VARIABLES INSTEAD**:

```
INSERT INTO `card`(ProductName,ProductBarcode,ProductPakking,ProductPresent,ProductMinimuim,FotoUrl,DBid)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT '" . $ProductName . "','" . $ProductBarcode . "','" . $ProductPakking . "','" . $ProductPresent . "','" . $ProductMinimuim . "','" . $FotoUrl . "','" . $DBid ."') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ProductName FROM `card` WHERE
        `ProductName` = '" . $ProductName . "' AND
        `ProductBarcode` = '" . $ProductBarcode . "' AND
        `ProductPakking` = '" . $ProductPakking . "' AND
        `ProductPresent` = '" . $ProductPresent . "' AND
        `ProductMinimuim` = '" . $ProductMinimuim . "' AND
        `FotoUrl` = '" . $FotoUrl . "' AND
        `DBid` = '" . $DBid ."'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thank you for the anwersing, I will the the OPP part en the Bind variables later. I always want a working query before i do the bind variables part.

But it did not work

 the error is Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
 right syntax to use near '
         `ProductBarcode` = '8717333541583',
         `ProductPakking` = 'zak',  ' at line 6

Comment: Post the full query that's causing the issue.

Comment: I copy and paste your query into my code , but i still get the error

Comment: I need to see the exact query that's being run

Comment: Just echo out $query instead of running it. Post back

Comment: If I echo the query i get this:
INSERT INTO `card`(ProductName,ProductBarcode,ProductPakking,ProductPresent,ProductMinimuim,FotoUrl,DBid)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'brood','8717333541583','zak','-1937','11','img/img.svg','3') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM `card` WHERE
        `ProductName` = 'brood',
        `ProductBarcode` = '8717333541583',
        `ProductPakking` = 'zak',
        `ProductPresent` = '-1937',
        `ProductMinimuim` = '11',
        `FotoUrl` = 'img/img.svg',
        `DBid` = '3' )
) LIMIT 1

Comment: Edit your original post

Comment: all my tables in my DB are VARCHAR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118584/discussion-between-robin-de-cock-and-frankerz).

Comment: I've updated my answer @RobindeCock

Comment: Thank you agian, I think where almost there. Now I get this:

Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 1' at line 13

Comment: Fix this error on line 13, now this one Error description: Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Comment: At this point, I've edited my answer to fix a mistaken `)` that was left out, and fixed an issue with your column name.

Comment: THANK YOU , If you were here i probably huged you or something, you made my day ! now the BIND VARIABLES and i'm done :D thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please be sure to mark it as answered (With the checkmark below the arrows next to the answer).

Comment: Sorry I almost forget that